# Interpretation of log-transformed regression (Y = LN(Y)) when the independent variable (X) is a percentage

Tags: regression, interpretation, logarithm

First, I want to mention that I am not really experienced with statistics and thus I would kindly ask you to explain the answer to me like you would to a 5-year old. Secondly, I have read a lot of questions and I am still a bit confused about my case. I've got the following regression set up: $$ln(Y) = a + b_1*x$$

Thus, the dependent variable (house prices) is log transformed and the independent variable (change in GDP) is merely a percentage.

How do I interpret the result (the coefficient = 1.857)?

Comment: This question is answered in many places: please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=interpret+log+regression.

Comment: "Secondly, I have read a lot of questions and I am still a bit confused about my case" Please give us the chance to make a clearer lower-level explanation